# Unsure how to use ConfigurationManager to retrieve a collection of elements

Tags: c#, configuration

I have the following in my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>

  <services>
    <service Site="AAA1.1" Release="QA" Connection="..." Monitor="True"/>
    <service Site="AAB1.2" Release="QA" Connection="..." Monitor="True"/>
    <service Site="AAC1.2" Release="QA" Connection="..." Monitor="True"/>
    <service Site="AAD3.1" Release="QA" Connection="..." Monitor="True"/>
    <service Site="AAE3.2" Release="QA" Connection="..." Monitor="True"/>
    <service Site="AAF5.1" Release="QA" Connection="..." Monitor="True"/>
    <service Site="AAG5.2" Release="QA" Connection="..." Monitor="True"/>
  </services>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>

</configuration>
```

I know I can retrieve the 'services' section as follows:

```
var section = configuration.GetSection("services");
```

What I don't know how to do is to get the child collection of seven 'service' elements once I have the section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is arguable best practice to [create your own Custom Configuration Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) this allows you to strongly type your collection, set default values for parameters and handle things like duplicate entries etc.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know what Class you are using but XmlTextReader (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx) has all you need !

A good tutorial is here : http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmltextreader